# How to return two html contents from ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm developing a shopping cart application in PHP, I have two functions, first function is to display total items in to cart and second function list all products in cart.

How can I return this two function's html output back from AJAX?

Here is the php server side:

```
<?php
require '../init.php';
require $ROOT . '/functions/basic.php';
require $ROOT . '/functions/products.php';

if(isset($_REQUEST['id']))
{

    $product_id = $_REQUEST['id'];

    $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] = isset($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]) ? $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] : "";
    if($product_id && !productExists($product_id)) {
        die("Error. Product Doesn't Exist");
    }

    $qty = dbRow("SELECT id, quantity FROM products WHERE id = $product_id");
    $quantity = $qty['quantity'];
    if($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] < $quantity)
    {
        $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] += 1; //add one to the quantity of the product with id $product_id

    }

}

function writeCartTotal()
{
    echo '
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href="carts"><h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> 
    ';        
                if(isset($_SESSION['cart']))
                {
                    $cart_count=count($_SESSION['cart']);
                    echo $cart_count;
                }
                else{
                    echo "0";
                }
    echo '
         items
        </h1></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h1>
    ';
            if(!empty($_SESSION['cart'])) { //if the cart isn't empty
                $total = "";
                $total_score = "";
                //iterate through the cart, the $product_id is the key and $quantity is the value
                foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product_id => $quantity) { 

                    //get the name, description and price from the database - this will depend on your database implementation.
                    //use sprintf to make sure that $product_id is inserted into the query as a number - to prevent SQL injection
                    $sql = dbQuery("SELECT product_title, product_description, price, product_score FROM products WHERE id = " . $product_id); 
                    $count = $sql->rowCount();

                    //Only display the row if there is a product (though there should always be as we have already checked)
                    if($count > 0) {

                        list($name, $description, $price, $score) = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

                        $line_cost = $price * $quantity; //work out the line cost
                        $line_score = $score * $quantity;
                        $total = $total + $line_cost; //add to the total cost
                        $total_score = $total_score + $line_score;
                    }

                }
                //show the total

                echo '<span class="label label-success">'. number_format($total) . " <span> ₭</span></span>";
    echo '      
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h1>
    ';   
                echo '<span class="label label-success">'. number_format($total_score) . " <span > PG</span></span>";



            }else{
            //otherwise tell the user they have no items in their cart
                echo "0";

            }
    echo '
        </h1>
    </div>
    ';
}

function writeCartSummary()
{
    echo '<h1>Welcome to Your Cart</h1>';
    if(!empty($_SESSION['cart'])) { //if the cart isn't empty
        $total = "";
        $total_score = "";
    //show the cart

        echo "<table class=\"table table-hovered table-bordered\" border=\"1\" padding=\"3\" width=\"40%\">"; //format the cart using a HTML table
        echo '<tr>
                <th align="center">Product Name</th>
                <th align="center">Quantity</th>
                <th align="center">Price</th>
                <th align="center">Score</th>
                <th align="center">Delete</th>
                </tr>';


        //iterate through the cart, the $product_id is the key and $quantity is the value
        foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product_id => $quantity) { 

            //get the name, description and price from the database - this will depend on your database implementation.
            //use sprintf to make sure that $product_id is inserted into the query as a number - to prevent SQL injection
            $sql = dbQuery("SELECT product_title, product_description, price, product_score FROM products WHERE id = " . $product_id); 
            $count = $sql->rowCount();

            //Only display the row if there is a product (though there should always be as we have already checked)
            if($count > 0) {

                list($name, $description, $price, $score) = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

                $line_cost = $price * $quantity; //work out the line cost
                $line_score = $score * $quantity;
                $total = $total + $line_cost; //add to the total cost
                $total_score = $total_score + $line_score;

                echo "<tr>";
                //show this information in table cells
                echo "<td align=\"center\">$name</td>";
                //along with a 'remove' link next to the quantity - which links to this page, but with an action of remove, and the id of the current product
                echo "<td align=\"center\">$quantity</td>";
                echo "<td align=\"center\"><h4>". number_format($line_cost) . " <span class='label label-success'> ₭</span></h4></td>";
                echo "<td align=\"center\"><h4>". number_format($line_score) . " <span class='label label-success'> PG</span></h4></td>";
                echo '<td><a href="?action=delete&amp;id='.$product_id.'" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a>';
                echo "</tr>";

            }

        }

        //show the total
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td colspan=\"2\" align=\"right\"><h1>Total</h1></td>";
        echo "<td align=\"right\"><h1>". number_format($total) . " <span class='label label-success'> ₭</span></h1></td>";
        echo "<td align=\"right\"><h1>". number_format($total_score) . " <span class='label label-success'> PG</span></h1></td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        //show the empty cart link - which links to this page, but with an action of empty. A simple bit of javascript in the onlick event of the link asks the user for confirmation
        echo "</table>";



    }else{
    //otherwise tell the user they have no items in their cart
        echo "<div class='well'><h3>You have no items in your shopping cart.</h3></div>";

    }
}
$value = array("response"=>"OK","totals"=>writeCartTotal(), "summaries"=>writeCartSummary());

echo json_encode($value);
?>
```

And this is the AJAX call method:

```
function isNumber(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("a.add_to_cart").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var productname = $(".product_name_page").attr('id');

    if(isNumber(id))
    {
        //alert("OK");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "ajax/ajaxAddToCart.php",
            data: "id=" + id,
            dataType: "html",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                if(data.response == "OK")
                {
                    swal("Success!", productname, "success");
                    $("#load_item_total").html(data.totals);
                    $("#navbar_shopping_cart").html(data.summaries); 
                }
                else
                {
                    $.alert({
                        title: '<h3 style="color: red;">Error!</h3>',
                        content: "<span class=''>There is an error, please try again!</span>",
                        confirm: function(){

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
 });
});
```

My question is how to return this two html contents function from AJAX?

I used json_encode() to return but I get no luck

Please help...!

Comment: whatever tou echo in php file that you will get in success function(data) data contains value that you have echo in ajax called file you can use it

Comment: You should not be echoing in your functions, instead add it to a variable and return that.

Comment: @jeroen you mean declare a variable for these two function instead of return the function its name right?

Comment: No, instead of echoing out html in your functions, you should build a string with that html and return that from your functions. Note that @MarioA's solution would work as well but that is kind of working around the problem instead of solving it.

Comment: Can you show some example? because if I only echoing to return only one function then it works perfect, but I need two because I need to refresh two html content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are echoing the html out instead of storing it in a string. To fix this, the fastest way is to redirect the echo outputs to a php variable:

```
ob_start();
writeCartSummary();
$cartSummary = ob_get_clean();

ob_start();
writeCartTotal();
$cartTotal = ob_get_clean();

$value = array("response"=>"OK","totals"=>$cartTotal , "summaries"=>$cartSummary );

echo json_encode($value);
```

With `ob_start` and `ob_get_clean` you redirect the echo from the standard outputbuffer to a variable. And by that you can put the variable content into your json data.

Further, with json-data as response, you need to use `dataType: 'json'` in your ajax call:

```
 $.ajax({
   /* ... */
   dataType: "json",
   /* ... */
 });
```

Comment: I tried your code but I still get the error alert, is it caused by the condition from the AJAX?

Comment: You need `dataType: "json"` in your ajax call instead of `html`. If there are still errors try to debug using a javascript console.

Comment: Wow... Thanks, change dataType: "json" as you mentioned now work perfect! thank you very much for help.